# Is Apple throttling web apps on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-app

According to the [Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/15/apple_ios_throttles_web_apps_on_home_screen/) Apple is throttling web apps:

> If a web app is run from the iOS 4.3 home screen – in other words, if
>   it is saved to the screen alongside local apps downloaded from the
>   Apple App Store – and launched into full-screen mode, it runs roughly
>   two to two and a half times slower than it does in the browser,
>   according to various tests. It appears that whereas Apple has updated
>   the iOS 4.3 Safari browser with its high-speed Nitro JavaScript
>   engine, Nitro is not used when web apps are launched from the home
>   screen.

Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more that Safari was being boosted in 4.3 and that that boost was not available to Web Apps on the homescreen

According to [ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/06/ios-5-brings-nitro-speed-to-home-screen-web-apps.ars) this is fixed in iOS 5.